# Select query returned resultSet but when creating view with the same query getting ORA-00957

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm new in the SQL world and I find this problem pretty annoying. In my workplace, I was asked to create a view from working query which being used in Crystal reports. When I execute the query I do get resultSet, but when I try to create a view with the exact same query I'm getting ORA-00957 error which means that I got duplicate column name. the query is huge and it's a nightmare to start making alias's, Is it possible to find another solution for this problem.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: please Show your code

Comment: You have to alias at least the duplicate column names; or eliminate the duplicates if they hold the same values anyway. You can do that as part of the `create view` without having to modify the query though.

Comment: I really dont get it, how does the select return resultSet, and the create view shout out an error???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the query itself, you can define the aliases as part of the view definition, [as shown in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html):

```
create view your_view (alias1, alias2, alias3, ...)
as <your query>
```

Of course the number of aliases has to match the number of columns in the result set, and you have to get them in the right order.

As a trivial example, lets say you have a query like:

```
select dummy, dummy from dual;

DUMMY  DUMMY 
------ ------
X      X
```

If you try to just convert that straight into a view you get the error you see:

```
create view v as
select dummy, dummy from dual;

Error report -
ORA-00957: duplicate column name
```

If you add aliases in the view definition, without changing the query, it works:

```
create view v (alias1, alias2) as
select dummy, dummy from dual;

View V created.

desc v

Name   Null? Type        
------ ----- ----------- 
ALIAS1       VARCHAR2(1) 
ALIAS2       VARCHAR2(1) 

select * from v;

ALIAS1 ALIAS2
------ ------
X      X
```

Comment: Mmmmm sounds interesting, i'll give it a try, thank you!